# angular.js:14077 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllContacts' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, factory

Basically I have a factory that pull the whole content in both tables (contacts and organizations)
I have this factory:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('appContacts')
        .factory('dataService', ['$q', '$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($q, $http) {

        return {
            getAllContacts: getAllContacts,
            getAllOrganizations: getAllOrganizations
        };

        function getAllContacts() {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/allcontacts',
            })
            .then(sendResponseData)
            .catch(sendGetBooksError)
        }

        function getAllOrganizations() {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/organizations',
            })
            .then(sendResponseData)
            .catch(sendGetBooksError)
        }

        function sendResponseData(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
        function sendGetBooksError(response) {
            return $q.reject('Error retrieving contact(s). (HTTP status: ' + response.status + ')');
        }
    }
})();
```

And I call it from this Controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('appContacts')
        .controller('contactsController', ['$q', 'dataService', '$http', contactsController]);

    function contactsController($q, $http, $state, dataService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.allcontacts = [];
            vm.contacts = [];
            vm.organizations = [];
            vm.phones = [];

            // Load all organizations  
             dataService.getAllOrganizations()
                .then(vm.organizations = getAllOrganizations)

            // Load all contacts  
            dataService.getAllContacts()
                .then(vm.allcontacts = getAllContacts);
//more stuff
```

But I get the error:
    **angular.js:14077 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAllContacts' of undefined**

Any Idea what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your injection is not correct. Injected services and factories must be aligned (injected in the same order that they are referenced):

```
.controller('contactsController',['$q', 'dataService', '$http', contactsController])

function contactsController($q, $http, $state, dataService)
```

This means that `$q` is(correctly) `'$q'`, `$http` is `'dataService'`, `$state` is `'$http'`, and dataService is not defined. (You are also missing the `'$state'` injection)

This is what you want:

```
.controller('contactsController',['$q', 'dataService', '$http', '$state', contactsController])

function contactsController($q, dataService, $http, $state)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I get another error: 

angular.js:14077 ReferenceError: getAllOrganizations is not defined
    at new contactsController (contactsController.js:41)

That is in the line:
             dataService.getAllOrganizations()
                .then(vm.organizations = getAllOrganizations)

Should I declare also the variable getAllOrganizations in the controller?
AngujarJS documentation is not really clear about details :-(